# Is it possible to iterate through the *values* of the items of a dir()?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class random_class():

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def iterate(self):
        for item in dir(self):
            print (self.item)

instance = random_class("blue")

random_class.iterate(instance)
```

But if I do that then I get:

```
AttributeError: 'random_class' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Which means that it's searching for an attribute named `item` in the instance

Comment: don't use `dir` for this, use `vars`. `dir` should not be used for anything aside from debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the properties you would drop the self keyword as it isn't needed since you are already pulling the value from dir.

If you want the actual value however you can use `getattr` to get the value in your loop.

```
class random_class():

def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color

def iterate(self):
    for item in dir(self):
        print (getattr(self, item))

instance = random_class("blue")

random_class.iterate(instance)
```

That would dump out the associated value to that property on your object.

**EDIT**

Note, the above will include the built in methods on a class. If you don't want that just ignore items that start with __

```
class random_class():

def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color

def iterate(self):
    for item in dir(self):
        if not item.startswith('__'):
            print (getattr(self, item))

instance = random_class("blue")

random_class.iterate(instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` refers to the variable defined by the loop, not an attribute of the object. So simply replace `print(self.item)` with `print(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

`item` refers to the variable in the loop, not an attribute of the object. So you can simply print `item`, and remove the `self.`.

Code:

```
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since item isn't an attribute of random_class, you can just print the item instead of self.item:

```
class random_class():

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def iterate(self):
        for item in dir(self):
            print (item)

instance = random_class("blue")

random_class.iterate(instance)
```